# How to set proper IAM role(s) for an AWS Batch job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-batch

I have a job that, after submission to the Batch service, goes from RUNNABLE to FAILED state, with the following job status error message (from AWS Console):

```
ECS was unable to assume the role 'arn:aws:iam::347134692569:role/my-custom-role' that was provided for this task. Please verify that the role being passed has the proper trust relationship and permissions and that your IAM user has permissions to pass this role.
```

The role referenced above is managed with Terraform, with two policy attachments (`AWSBatchServiceRole` and `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role`) like so:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "batch" {
  name               = "my-custom-role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement":
    [
      {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "batch.amazonaws.com"
          }
      },
      {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
          }
      },
      {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "ecs.amazonaws.com"
          }
      }
    ]
}
EOF
  tags = {
    Terraform = "true"
  }
}

# attach a policy to the role that allows using AWS Batch service
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "batch_service_role" {
  role       = data.aws_iam_role.batch.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSBatchServiceRole"
}

# attach a policy to the role that allows using AWS Elastic Container service
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "elastic_container_service_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.batch.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
}
```

The above role is used as the compute environment's service role as well as the job role for job definition.

It seems that the above doesn't provide sufficient permission to enable assuming the role and/or necessary trust relationship(s). What else can I try to get past this error?

Comment: The error seems to be about your IAM user or role which you use to create the batch job missing `iam:PassRole` permissions. You can add to yourself, or the role which you use, the missing `PassRole` permission, and check with that.

Comment: Other possibility is that there need to be permission for `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com` in a trust policy to assume the role.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Marcin. Adding the assume role for `ecs-tasks` did the trick. I'm curious, how would I have figured this out myself? I have not seen anything about this in any example/tutorial/documentation.

Comment: Glad to hear. I will add an answer for future reference if you don't mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the comments, the issue was solved by adding `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com` as a principle for `AssumeRole`.

Seems that same permissions were required as those for ECS task execution role and the task:

- [Amazon ECS Task Execution IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html)
- [IAM Roles for Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html#create_task_iam_policy_and_role)